Does order of quantifiers matter when dealing only with unary predicates?
When using only unary predicates, does the order of quantifiers in the formula matter? For instance when we have formula:
$$\forall x \, \exists y \, (\phi(x) \lor \psi(y))$$
and formula
$$\exists y \, \forall x \, (\phi(x) \lor \psi(y))$$
are they equivalent?

@TankutBeygu That doesn’t seem similar at all. The linked question is about permuting the order of quantifiers in general (or permuting adjacent and same quantifiers in specific), while the OP’s question is about whether the order of quantifiers can be permuted when only unary predicates are allowed. These are quite different questions.

Try the formulas $\forall x \exists y \; \left((A(x) \land A(y)) \vee (\neg A(x) \land \neg A(y))\right)$
and $\exists y \forall x \; \left((A(x) \land A(y)) \vee (\neg A(x) \land \neg A(y))\right)$.
The first is true: take $y = x$. The second is false, assuming there are some $x$ with $A(x)$ true and others with $A(x)$ false.
